# Project array item from document

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

imagine I have the following class setup which I store in my MongoDB collection:

```
public class Person
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<Person> Children { get; set; }
}
```

So a singular document inside of the collection might look like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("<<myObjectId>>"), 
    "FirstName" : "James",
    "LastName" : "Bond",
    "Children" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("<<myObjectId>>"), 
            "FirstName" : "Peter",
            "LastName" : "Bond",
            "Children" : null
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("<<myObjectId>>"), 
            "FirstName" : "Thomas",
            "LastName" : "Bond",
            "Children" : null
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("<<myObjectId>>"), 
            "FirstName" : "Henry",
            "LastName" : "Bond",
            "Children" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

From the children of James I now want to find the ones that are named Thomas. I can achieve this with the following projection:

```
var projection = Builders<Person>
            .Projection
            .ElemMatch(person => person.Children, child => child.LastName == "Bond")
            .Exclude(person => person._id);
```

When I now specify my FindOptions as `FindOptions<Person, Person>` the result is:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("0000000000000"), 
    "FirstName" : null,
    "LastName" : null,
    "Children" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("<<myObjectId>>"), 
            "FirstName" : "Thomas",
            "LastName" : "Bond",
            "Children" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

For me this is not ideal since I'd rather like to have an `IEnumerable<Person>` as a result. I know that I could create it myself from the result I receive but I'm wondering if there is a native support for this?

I'm using MongoDB.Driver 2.7.0 with the Community Edition of MongoDB in the version 4.0.2.

Thanks for your help in advance!